# "Nobody answered" plugin for Gmail?

Tags: gmail, reminder

Sometimes I will send a message in Gmail and expect someone to answer. If they don't answer, I will forget to remind them to.

Is there a plugin that would do that? For example, if I don’t receive a reply to my email, remind me to resend that email or ask "what happened".

The more portable the solution, the better. Don't forget we login from multiple places. We also use smartphones.

Comment: Similar question on SuperUser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/334095/how-do-i-get-a-remind-for-emails-i-sent-that-remain-unanswered-after-a-period-of

Answer (score 2):

There are two plugins available that provide various scheduling functions, including reminders for unanswered email:

- [Boomerang](http://www.boomeranggmail.com/)
- [RightInbox](http://www.rightinbox.com/)

Both are available for Firefox and Chrome.  They both also use the "Freemium" model.  You can schedule up to 10 emails per month for free; if you need more than 10 per month, they offer monthly and annual subscription plans that include unlimited scheduling.

(I have no affiliation with either of these products -- I read about them while searching for something else yesterday.)

Comment: They both have what I'm looking for. But these are browser plugins. Not very portable. What about when I'm on my iPhone?

Comment: Unless and until Google adds that sort of functionality your only options are going to be browser-specific scripts, which means they're not going to work on mobile browsers, or third-party services to which you will need to give access to your Gmail account.

Comment: Don't they have some API in Labs?